# Locks in SQL Server Across Transactions

Tags: sql-server, transactions, locking

Here is my scenario why I need a row lock across transactions..

- change the columns value to 5 (in SQL Server)
- change the columns value to 5 (in another resource, this can be a file or etc.)

Of course it's the case when everything is gone well. but if any problem occurs while doing the second change operation, I need to rollback the first change. And also while doing the second change, nobody should be allowed to read or to write this row in SQL Server.

So I need to do that

- lock the column
- change the columns value to 5 (in SQL Server)
- change the columns value to 5 (in another resource)
- if the above change is successfully done
    commit the column
  else
    rollback the column
- unlock the column

And I also need something for the murphy case. If I cannot reach the database after locking the row (in order to unlock or to rollback), it should be unlocked in a few seconds.

Is it possible to have something to do that in SQL Server or what ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read up on distributed transactions and a compensating ressource manager. THen you realize you can do all that in ONE transaction, managed by your transaction coordinator.

Comment: thanks for your recommendations.
i was searching for an easy solution but it seems there is not one. i will dig into this topic later when other so many things needs to be done is done :)